# Upload Video Directly to Vimeo from Client via API

Tags: security, upload, vimeo, vimeo-api

I want to upload a video directly to Vimeo via API without having to upload it to my backend server. In Amazon S3, I would [generated a signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585881/amazon-s3-direct-file-upload-from-client-browser-private-key-disclosure) on the backend and use it on the frontend form. However, in Vimeo, it looks like I need to provide the API token in the header to [upload a video](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos).

In this case, how do I upload a video directly to Vimeo on the client side without compromising security? I assume it's not safe to reveal the API token on the client side and there's no setting in Vimeo that lets me restrict the origin URL for file uploading.

Comment: use Tus approach as documented in Vimeo api, generate the upload URL in server side and use https://github.com/tus/tus-js-client while giving it that upload URL to upload the video to vimeo. see my Q for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726862/resume-file-uploading-using-tus-protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vimeo has a [tutorial](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos) for uploading videos from your own frontend with HTTP requests.

Comment: The documentation was a little confusing but it was a two-step process. You submit the initial request on the backend to get the URL to upload the file to, and use it on the client.